# Get data type of variable

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion

```
@interface testing
@property NSString *email;
@property NSString *password;
@end
```

In another class , how to get data type of email, or password without defined the email and password.

```
NSArray *keys=[[NSArray alloc] init];
[keys addObject:@"email"]; 
testing *detail=[[testing alloc]init]; 
if([[detail valueForKey:keys[0]] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
 { NSLog("This is string class variable"); }
```

but it not enter the if condition

Comment: NSString is class type not dataType. And email,password are instances of NSString class. You can access there class anywhere by using [email class]

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to obtain the class of a property is

```
[email class];
[password class];
```

There are ways to test the object class as well using `isKindOfClass:` and `isMemberOfClass:` and even `isSubclassOfClass:`

You can use these in `if statements` like

```
if([email isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
```

and/or

```
if([password isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]])
```

and/or

```
if([[email class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSString class]])
```

For a description of each these please read the [Apple Documentation on `NSObject` class reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/isSubclassOfClass:) and [Apple Documentation on `NSObject` protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)

**isSubclassOfClass:**

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiving class is a subclass of, or identical to, a given class.
>   `+ (BOOL)isSubclassOfClass:(Class)aClass`
>   Parameters
>
> aClass
>
> A class object.
>
> Return Value
>
> YES if the receiving class is a subclass of—or identical to—aClass, otherwise NO.
>   Availability
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>
> Declared In
>   objc/NSObject.h

**isKindOfClass:**

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class. (required)
>   `- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass`
>   Parameters
>
> aClass
>
> A class object representing the Objective-C class to be tested.
>
> Return Value
>
> YES if the receiver is an instance of aClass or an instance of any class that inherits from aClass, otherwise NO.
>   Discussion
>
> For example, in this code, isKindOfClass: would return YES because, in Foundation, the NSArchiver class inherits from NSCoder:
>
> `NSMutableData *myData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:30];`
>
> `id anArchiver = [[NSArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:myData];`
>
> `if ( [anArchiver isKindOfClass:[NSCoder class]] )`
>
> `...`
>
> Be careful when using this method on objects represented by a class cluster. Because of the nature of class clusters, the object you get back may not always be the type you expected. If you call a method that returns a class cluster, the exact type returned by the method is the best indicator of what you can do with that object. For example, if a method returns a pointer to an NSArray object, you should not use this method to see if the array is mutable, as shown in the following code:
>
> // DO NOT DO THIS!
>
> `if ([myArray isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])`
>
> `{`
>
> `// Modify the object`
>
> `}`
>
> If you use such constructs in your code, you might think it is alright to modify an object that in reality should not be modified. Doing so might then create problems for other code that expected the object to remain unchanged.
>
> If the receiver is a class object, this method returns YES if aClass is a Class object of the same type, NO otherwise.
>   Availability
>
> Available in OS X v10.0 and later.
>
> See Also
>
> `– isMemberOfClass:`
>
> Related Sample Code
>
> QuickLookSketch
>      Sketch
>      Sketch+Accessibility
>
> Declared In
>   objc/NSObject.h

**isMemberOfClass:**

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of a given class. (required)
>   `- (BOOL)isMemberOfClass:(Class)aClass`
>   Parameters
>
> aClass
>
> A class object representing the Objective-C class to be tested.
>
> Return Value
>
> YES if the receiver is an instance of aClass, otherwise NO.
>   Discussion
>
> For example, in this code, isMemberOfClass: would return NO:
>
> `NSMutableData *myData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:30];`
>
> `id anArchiver = [[NSArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:myData];`
>
> `if ([anArchiver isMemberOfClass:[NSCoder class]])`
>
> `...`
>
> Class objects may be compiler-created objects but they still support the concept of membership. Thus, you can use this method to verify that the receiver is a specific Class object.
>   Availability
>
> Available in OS X v10.0 and later.
>
> See Also
>
> `– isKindOfClass:`
>
> Declared In
>   objc/NSObject.h

**EDIT**

When trying to access these properties in another class (Which isn't what you are asking in your question) do the following.

```
Testing *testingClassIVar = [[Testing alloc] init];
[testingClassIVar email];
[testingClassIVar password];

// to get the class type of these
[[testingClassIVar email] class];
[[testingClassIVar password] class];
```

**EDIT 2**

OMG just **NO** I don't even know what you are trying to do but it seems very wrong. `NSArray` doesn't respond to `addObject:` so this will crash your code. If you want to use `addObject:` then change the `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` but unless you plan on using that array in a loop (If you are please specify I will not assume) then just access the property by using `[detail email]`

Change to this

```
testing *detail= [[testing alloc] init];

if([[detail email] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) { 
    NSLog("This is string class variable"); 
}
```

Comment: i am creating object of testing in another class then how to get data type of email or password.

Comment: @user2906108 see my edit, but you aren't very clear about what you want. Are you just wanting to access those properties or are you wanting to get the class type of those properties?

Comment: this is my code
===================
    NSArray *keys=[[NSArray alloc] init];
    [keys addObject:@"email"];
    testing *detail=[[testing alloc]init];
     if([[detail valueForKey:keys[0]] isKindOfClass:[NSString   class]])
     {
       NSLog("This is string class variable");
     } 


but it not enter the if condition

Comment: All you are doing there is creating an array and adding an string object to it that says email. However that should break because `keys` is not mutable so doesn't respond to `addObject:` Please share all your code as you have it in your question, I suspect that you have many issues because you do in what you have just shared in your comment. Once you share all your code in your question I will be able to provide a better answer to your question.

Comment: Popeye sir,
this is requirement for project

Comment: @user2906108 Your requirement is to crash your code with a `-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`? That seems like a stupid requirement. Please detail your requirements properly and what you are wanting to do. Are you wanting to loop through an array an access each of the properties listed in the array? What you haven't told us much and I am being to get the opinion I should have just voted to close the question as unclear what you are asking.